# Oracle loop through file list

Tags: oracle11g

I am writing a procedure to move some files with Oracle 11g. There are about 5 different types of log/dsc files that can be generated on any given day. Although not all of them are guaranteed to be created. I plan to rename the file with the appended date and move to a corresponding sub directory.

I am ideally making this procedure to move all the files in one fell swoop. I have never attempted this in PL/SQL.

I would normally work with an array of file names and iterate through them. But I wasn't sure how to do this in Oracle. My current solution is to literally call the procedure and pass the file name as an argument to it each time. But I'd like something more automated and wasn't sure of how to proceed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FTP_MOVER(i_dir VARCHAR2, i_file VARCHAR2) AS

v_file_append VARCHAR2(50);
v_file_rename VARCHAR2(50);
v_destination_dir VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN

        -- append date
        v_file_append := TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'YYYYMMDD');
        -- new file name
        v_file_rename := v_file_append||i_file;

        IF SUBSTR(i_file, -3) = 'log' THEN

            -- set log destination dir
            v_destination_dir := 'HISTORY_LOG';

        ELSE IF SUBSTR(i_file, -3) = 'dsc' THEN

            -- set log destination dir
            v_destination_dir := 'HISTORY_DSC';

            END IF;

        END IF;

        -- move log file to history/log
        UTL_FILE.FRENAME(i_dir,
                         i_file, 
                         v_destination_dir, 
                         v_file_rename);                        

END FTP_TIDY;
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this in pl/sql vs just a simple OS script?

Comment: @OldProgrammer There's no advantage. It's just required to be done as part of the DB application's management.

Comment: There is no pl/sql function I know of that will scan a diretory.  You would need to write a java stored proc to call. See here - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584

Comment: @OldProgrammer I thought that might be the case, I wondered if you could use an array() of the file names and iterate through the array. I believe they exist in Oracle. However I've never come across a piece of code which utilizes them.

Comment: @Jonnny no Java external RPC is required see this article which was linked back to the Asktom article pointed out by OldProgrammer http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513 but ofcourse some OS level script will be needed to list the files (like a .sh, .ksh or .bat script) as a preprocessor to the external table.